# section title with IfStrEq formula in \sethead

Tags: header-footer, xifthen

I want to include in `\sethead` the section title. I use `\IfStrEq` formula like this:

```
IfStrEq{\bottitlemarks\sectiontitle}{\firsttitlemarks\sectiontitle}{\firsttitlemarks \sectiontitle}{\firsttitlemarks \sectiontitle \:- \bottitlemarks \sectiontitle}
```

but it always return `false`. Even the bottom section title is equal first section title...

This is a short example of my tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %system kodowania fontów
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{xifthen, xstring}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \IfStrEq \str_if_eq:nnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\bottomTitle}{\bottitlemarks\sectiontitle}
\newcommand{\topTitle}{\firsttitlemarks\sectiontitle}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{titleps,lipsum}
\newpagestyle{main}{
\sethead
  [\thepage]
  []
  [\IfStrEq{\topTitle}{\bottomTitle}{\firsttitlemarks \sectiontitle}{\firsttitlemarks \sectiontitle \:- \bottitlemarks \sectiontitle}]
  {\IfStrEq{\firsttitlemarks \sectiontitle}{\bottitlemarks \sectiontitle}{\firsttitlemarks \sectiontitle}{\firsttitlemarks \sectiontitle \quad - \quad \bottitlemarks \sectiontitle}}
  {}% centre
  {\thepage}% right
  \setheadrule{.4pt}% Regular header rule
}
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
    \section{blah}
    a
\end{document}
```

In headder is doubled section title but i create just one section so first section == botom section

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since you're not using standard LaTeX commands, but those offered by additional packages, it's necessary to show a short example of a document with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:
First your `\IfStrEq` is defined as `\str_if_eq:nnTF`, so it will not expand the strings before comparing them. So even if e.g. `\topTitle` and `\bottomTitle` would expand to the same value, they would be different in the eyes of `\IfStrEq` because the unexpanded text is different. This can be fixed by using `\str_if_eq_x:nnTF` instead, so replace

```
\cs_set_eq:NN \IfStrEq \str_if_eq:nnTF
```

with

```
\cs_set_eq:NN \IfStrEq \str_if_eq_x:nnTF
```

Second, the argument is only expanded but not executed by TeXs stomach, so commands like `\bottitlemarks` do not work there.
So you have to call `\bottilemarks` / `\firsttitlemarks` outside of `\IfStrEq`. You can't have both active during the `\IfStrEq` call, but you can save one of the `\sectiontitle`s in a macro:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %system kodowania fontów
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{xifthen, xstring}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \IfStrEq \str_if_eq_x:nnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage[extramarks]{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \sethead
  [\thepage]
  []
  [%
    \bottitlemarks
    \let\botsectiontitle\sectiontitle
    \toptitlemarks
    \IfStrEq{\sectiontitle}{\botsectiontitle}{%
      \sectiontitle
    }{%
      \sectiontitle \quad --\quad \botsectiontitle
    }%
  ]
  {%
    \bottitlemarks
    \let\botsectiontitle\sectiontitle
    \toptitlemarks
    \IfStrEq{\sectiontitle}{\botsectiontitle}{%
      \sectiontitle
    }{%
      \sectiontitle \quad --\quad \botsectiontitle
    }%
  }
  {}% centre
  {\thepage}% right
  \setheadrule{.4pt}% Regular header rule
}
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
  \section{blah}
  \lipsum
  \section{blah2}
  \section{blah3}
\end{document}
```

This also uses the `\topmark` instead of the `\firstmark`. Output:

[image]